# The Python code I created using Python and Tensorflow does not work as I want

Tags: tensorflow, chess, python-chess

I wrote two codes, one of which generates random moves, evaluates them with Stockfish, and then trains them to create a model. Other code for using this model and playing with it.

```
import chess
import chess.engine
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import tensorflow as tf
from tqdm import tqdm
import random

STOCKFISH_PATH = "/Users/berkegulacar/Downloads/stockfish"
ENGINE_TIME_LIMIT = 1.0
NUM_GAMES = 500

def evaluate_board(engine, board):
    with engine.analysis(board, limit=chess.engine.Limit(time=ENGINE_TIME_LIMIT)) as analysis:
        for info in analysis:
            if info.get("score") is not None:
                return info.get("score").white().score(mate_score=10000)
    return

def board_to_input(board):
    piece_to_index = {
        'P': 0, 'N': 1, 'B': 2, 'R': 3, 'Q': 4, 'K': 5,
        'p': 6, 'n': 7, 'b': 8, 'r': 9, 'q': 10, 'k': 11
    }
    board_planes = np.zeros((64, 12), dtype=np.float32)
    for square in chess.SQUARES:
        piece = board.piece_at(square)
        if piece:
            index = piece_to_index[piece.symbol()]
            board_planes[square, index] = 1
    board_planes = board_planes.reshape((8, 8, 12))
    extra_features = np.zeros((8, 8, 5), dtype=np.float32)
    extra_features[:, :, 0] = int(board.has_kingside_castling_rights(chess.WHITE))
    extra_features[:, :, 1] = int(board.has_queenside_castling_rights(chess.WHITE))
    extra_features[:, :, 2] = int(board.has_kingside_castling_rights(chess.BLACK))
    extra_features[:, :, 3] = int(board.has_queenside_castling_rights(chess.BLACK))
    if board.ep_square:
        ep_square = np.unravel_index(board.ep_square, (8, 8))
        extra_features[ep_square[0], ep_square[1], 4] = 1
    turn_channel = np.full((8, 8, 1), int(board.turn == chess.BLACK), dtype=np.float32)
    board_input = np.concatenate((board_planes, extra_features, turn_channel), axis=-1)
    return board_input

def play_game(engine):
    board = chess.Board()
    game_data = []
    while not board.is_game_over(claim_draw=True):
        move = random.choice(list(board.legal_moves))
        board.push(move)
        score = evaluate_board(engine, board)
        game_data.append((board_to_input(board), score))
    return game_data

def play_and_collect_data(num_games, engine_path):
    engine = chess.engine.SimpleEngine.popen_uci(engine_path)
    games_data = []
    for _ in tqdm(range(num_games), desc="Playing games and collecting data"):
        games_data.extend(play_game(engine))
    engine.quit()
    return games_data

def preprocess_data(games_data):
    X, y = zip(*games_data)
    X = np.array(X, dtype=np.float32)
    y = np.array(y, dtype=np.float32) / 10000
    return train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.1, random_state=42)

def create_model(input_shape):
    model = Sequential([
        Dense(512, activation='relu', input_shape=input_shape),
        Dropout(0.2),
        Dense(512, activation='relu'),
        Dropout(0.2),
        Dense(1, activation='tanh')
    ])
    model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error')
    return model

def train_model(model, X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test):
    model.fit(X_train, y_train, validation_data=(X_test, y_test), epochs=50)
    return model

if __name__ == '__main__':
    games_data = play_and_collect_data(NUM_GAMES, STOCKFISH_PATH)
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = preprocess_data(games_data)
    model = create_model(X_train[0].shape)
    model = train_model(model, X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test)
    model.save('model.h5')
```

**And code for playing with model:
**

```
import chess
import chess.engine
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

MODEL_PATH = '/Users/berkegulacar/Downloads/model.h5'
STOCKFISH_PATH = '/Users/berkegulacar/Downloads/stockfish'

model = tf.keras.models.load_model(MODEL_PATH)
engine = chess.engine.SimpleEngine.popen_uci(STOCKFISH_PATH)

def board_to_input(board):
    piece_to_index = {
        'P': 0, 'N': 1, 'B': 2, 'R': 3, 'Q': 4, 'K': 5,
        'p': 6, 'n': 7, 'b': 8, 'r': 9, 'q': 10, 'k': 11
    }
    board_planes = np.zeros((64, 12), dtype=np.float32)
    for square in chess.SQUARES:
        piece = board.piece_at(square)
        if piece:
            index = piece_to_index[piece.symbol()]
            board_planes[square, index] = 1
    board_planes = board_planes.reshape((8, 8, 12))
    extra_features = np.zeros((8, 8, 5), dtype=np.float32)
    extra_features[:, :, 0] = int(board.has_kingside_castling_rights(chess.WHITE))
    extra_features[:, :, 1] = int(board.has_queenside_castling_rights(chess.WHITE))
    extra_features[:, :, 2] = int(board.has_kingside_castling_rights(chess.BLACK))
    extra_features[:, :, 3] = int(board.has_queenside_castling_rights(chess.BLACK))
    if board.ep_square:
        ep_square = np.unravel_index(board.ep_square, (8, 8))
        extra_features[ep_square[0], ep_square[1], 4] = 1
    turn_channel = np.full((8, 8, 1), int(board.turn == chess.BLACK), dtype=np.float32)
    board_input = np.concatenate((board_planes, extra_features, turn_channel), axis=-1)
    return board_input

def select_best_move(model, board, engine):
    legal_moves = list(board.legal_moves)
    best_move = None
    best_move_score = -np.inf

    for move in legal_moves:
        board.push(move)
        processed_board = board_to_input(board).reshape(1, 8, 8, 18)
        board_score = model.predict(processed_board)
        board.pop()
        current_move_score = board_score.flatten()[0]
        
        if current_move_score > best_move_score:
            best_move_score = current_move_score
            best_move = move

    if best_move is None:
        result = engine.play(board, chess.engine.Limit(time=0.1))
        best_move = result.move
        print("Stockfish's move: {best_move}")
    else:
        print(f"Model's move: {best_move}")

    return best_move

def play_game(model, engine):
    board = chess.Board()
    while not board.is_game_over(claim_draw=True):
        print(board)
        user_move = input("Your move (e.g., e2e4): ")
        try:
            move = chess.Move.from_uci(user_move)
            if move in board.legal_moves:
                board.push(move)
            else:
                print("Invalid move, try again.")
                continue
        except ValueError:
            print("Invalid move format, try again.")
            continue
        if board.is_game_over(claim_draw=True):
            break
        best_move = select_best_move(model, board, engine)
        board.push(best_move)
    print("Game result:", board.result())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    play_game(model, engine)
    engine.quit()
```

The problem is that I think there is a scoring error in the trained model, so no matter what I play, it always repeats the same and illogical g8h6 followed by h8g8 and g8h8 and is checkmated. I need help for this. I'm waiting for your help.

I tried fen to numeric and one-hot encoding but the result is the same.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to stack overflow!
First of all, g8h6 followed by h8g8 and g8h8 are the first legal moves generated by python chess, so it seems that your model always returns the same value. Indeed,

`if current_move_score > best_move_score:`

is never true if `current_move_score` is constant, so the first move is always picked. The reason it happens could be because of your normalization by 10000. Isn't the stockfish evaluation in centipawns? [This](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/6447) may help. Can you give some more info on the training results?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I don't understand what you want to know about the enterprise data. You can check the training data with h5dump, which I share with you here. Trained on 10 Games and 50 Epochs. https://pixeldrain.com/u/BmhmfiUi